# Show id element that has same name as class

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, function, select

```
<style>
    #africa,#bahrain,#oman{
        display:none
    }
</style>

<select class="country">
    <option class="africa" value="africa">Africa</option>
    <option class="bahrain" value="bahrain">Bahrain</option>
    <option class="oman" value="oman">Oman</option>
</select>

<div class="countryDetails">
    <div id="africa"><h1>Africa details</h1></div>
    <div id="bahrain"><h1>Bahrain details</h1></div>
    <div id="oman"><h1>Oman details</h1></div>
</div>
```

How would I create a function that, if i select a country from the dropdown list, the details of that country would show?

The `class` of the list item has the same name as the details, expect the details is an ID.

The list will continue to grow so it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: have you tried to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution

```js
var t=$('.country').val();

$('#'+t).show();

$('.country').on('change',function(){
    t=$('.country').val();
    $('.countryDetails').children().hide();
    $('#'+t).show();
});
```

```css
#africa,#bahrain,#oman{
        display:none
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="country">
    <option class="africa" value="africa">Africa</option>
    <option class="bahrain" value="bahrain">Bahrain</option>
    <option class="oman" value="oman">Oman</option>
</select>

<div class="countryDetails">
    <div id="africa"><h1>Africa details</h1></div>
    <div id="bahrain"><h1>Bahrain details</h1></div>
    <div id="oman"><h1>Oman details</h1></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    $('.countryDetails').children().hide();
    $('#' + this.value).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uvqxbvvL/)

If you haven't included jQuery to your project yet, better go with pure javascript as you won't need to load the whole jQuery lib for that.

You can use this instead:

```
var det = document.querySelectorAll('.countryDetails div');
var val = document.getElementById('country');

val.addEventListener('change',function(){
    for (var i = 0; i< det.length;i++){
        det[i].id != val.value ? det[i].style.display = 'none' :  det[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

note the id I added in the html for your country select

```
<select class="country" id="country">
    <option class="africa" value="africa">Africa</option>
    <option class="bahrain" value="bahrain">Bahrain</option>
    <option class="oman" value="oman">Oman</option>
</select>

<div class="countryDetails">
    <div id="africa"><h1>Africa details</h1></div>
    <div id="bahrain"><h1>Bahrain details</h1></div>
    <div id="oman"><h1>Oman details</h1></div>
</div>
```

### [DEMO PURE JS](http://jsfiddle.net/uvqxbvvL/2/)